# Adding elements of different type to arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains

So I have an arraylist which looks like this `ArrayList<Card> player1Hand = Player.Player1(seed);`
It contains `[KH, 9L, 7L, 8L, KE]` Every combination represents one card.
and an array `split[]` containing `[KH]`

Now I tried this:
`if (player1Hand.contains(split[2])) {//code}` Now the if statement does not get executed since split[] contains objects of type String and the arrayList contains objects of type `Card`. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: You can use a `Map<String,Card>` instead of `ArrayList<Card>` and use `map.containsKey(split[2])`

Comment: Additionally, does Card have an String constructor? You could do `player1hand.contains(new Card(split[2]))`. It is possible that you need to overload `equals` for this approach

Answer (score 1):

You should create a named constructor (from Effective Java J.Bloch) for your Card class and override `equals` and `hashCode` for it like this:

```
class Card {
    private String valueAsString;

    /*your code here*/
    
    public static Card of(String valueAsString) {
         Card card = /*create your card here*/
         card.valueAsString = valueAsString;
         return card;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
         /*another part of equals*/
         return Objects.equals(valueAsString, other.valueAsString);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
         return Objects.hash(valueAsString);
    }
}
```

With that named constructor you can just do the following thing:

```
    if (player1Hand.contains(Card.of(split[2]))) {
         /*do something*/
    }
```

The explanation: as soon as `ArrayList` uses an `equals` method to compare elements in the array you need to define it properly. Besides, a named constructor helps you to create a placeholder object based on value of `split[2]`. With this two steps you will be able to use `contains` and it will work as you want to. Why should you override a `hashCode` too? You should do it, because there is an informal rule that you should always override `equals` and `hashCode` like a pair, because they have to do it's stuff with the same set of fields.